# html_entities_decode cuts codeigniter output

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-entities

I am using PHP (5.2.13) with IIS6 and CodeIgniter framework, and I am handling problems with print data from database with html_entities_decode. For example:

```
<?php

echo html_entity_decode($somedata,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
echo "Hello";

?>
```

$somedata is $data["informativo"][0]->texto and texto is some html (html mix with xml sometimes) codes.

The problem is that the echo "Hello" is not showing, actually the $somedata does not print everything. All buffer after that echo is not showing as well.

Could be this problem with Output class from CodeIgniter?

---

I found that actually the query isn't bringing everything. The Database is MSSQL Server 2005 and the field texto is a long text.

The code of the query is:

```
<?php
    public function getInformativo($idInformativo)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT titulo,texto,secao,usu_atualizacao,data_atualizacao,inativo
                FROM PI_Informativo
                WHERE idInformativo = '".$idInformativo."'";
        return $this->db->query($sql)->result();    
    }
?>
```

The texto field only brings a part of that long text. The sql driver is ODBC.

But why the rest of php after the echo of $somedata does not showing? In the controller after that any loaded view are missing.

---

I Just found the answer. My connection with Database uses ODBC, and I need to specify a bigger long byte size with:

```
ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", "100K");
```

Comment: do you call `html_entity_decode()` inside of view?

Comment: I tried both on Controller and view and I got the same results.

Comment: I know what `html_entity_decode()` does, but please edit question and  provide `$somedata`, what is in it?

Comment: Please read after line break.  The sql driver is odbc.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use helper for this, more info can be found [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/string_helper.html)

```
//example from the site

$string="Joe's \"dinner\"";
$string=quotes_to_entities($string); //results in "Joe&#39;s &quot;dinner&quot;"
```

I just found this

```
- * In some versions of PHP the native function does not work
- * when UTF-8 is the specified character set, so this gives us
- * a work-around.  More info here:
- * http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25670
- *
- * NOTE: html_entity_decode() has a bug in some PHP versions when UTF-8 is the
- * character set, and the PHP developers said they were not back porting the
- * fix to versions other than PHP 5.x.
```

workaround in CI should be loading security library and use it like this

```
$this->load->library('security');
return $this->security->entity_decode($str, $charset);
```